# Reveal.js Sharable links to specific slide / Keep current slide on reload

Tags: reveal.js

Using Reveal.js, I can't find any documentation of this feature. I'm positive I've seen this somewhere. And I would sure like to be able to reload the page and not have to navigate through the entire deck every time.

Does it exist as a hidden feature? Does anyone know of a "plugin" or patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to set `history: true` in the configuraton at the end of the `index.html` page:

```
Reveal.initialize({
    history: true,
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The update from 2022 relevant for Reveal.JS 4.3.1:

Trick with history no longer works, use `hash` instead:

```js
 new Reveal({
    plugins: [Markdown, Highlight],
    hash: true,
  }).initialize();
```

[Link to the documentation](https://revealjs.com/config/)